# specific add-on tags

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Recently [a tag was created](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/41928/1) for *animation-nodes*, so I decided to also create the wiki tag for *sverchok*. These are both big non-trivial add-ons and totally deserve a tag. Before I start tagging the other Questions about Sverchok, and before I put more effort into the tag wiki I'd like to know if this is acceptable practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have said this before about other new tags, There should be no set right or wrong answer to whether or not "this" tag is ok. The question usage should drive the demand for a new tag.

That said, I'm not sure we need a sverchok tag now, seeing as there so few questions. It looks to me (after a quick [search](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=sverchok+is%3Aquestion)) like there are 4 questions that could use the [sverchok](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sverchok) tag.
However tag the sverchok questions, lets see how much use the [sverchok](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sverchok) tag gets, if it is popular by all means then it should be a tag.

I'm also leaning towards its own tag because it is something quite distinct; no other tag will work.

---

I have been surprised at new tag usage in the past,for what I thought would be a odd tag. So there is no way to know for sure until we give a new tag time in the open.

PS thanks for bringing this to meta.

Comment: I hold contradicting views about whether or not to encourage the specific tags. If it gathers traction I might warm to it.

Comment: @zeffii what is your position? Because at this point I think it is an ok thing to do. We can go to the chat.

Comment: i think if a question arises due to unclear/lacking documentation, the question should be directed at the issue-tracker of the specific add-on. The best thing for each add-on is to have satisfactory docs, not sporadic info on BSE. It's almost like a 'soft-bug', fix it once in the add-on repo and the question doesn't need to exist anymore.

Comment: You have a *very* good point. Yet what to tag all the real questions that can arise (even with documentation and video tutorials)? Because good docs will never stop all the questions.

Comment: On the other hand... asking for a tutorial / run throughs also enters this grey area.. where does Blender start and 'add-on' X begin ? :) In some cases the more elaborate add-ons can really be viewed as distinct pieces of software that just happen to run inside Blender.

Comment: Documentation can rarely be comprehensive to the extent that all potential questions are negated. But sometimes clearly the docs should be improved as a result of dealing with these questions (this also with respect to Blender itself... and I think it's not something we do generally...fix the docs when weakness is encountered)

Comment: Just a small typo, you used `weather` rather than `whether` in your second sentence. (I don't have full edit privileges)

Comment: @angussidney thank you.  PS you can always edit a post, just it will be reviewed first.

Comment: @David the edit button is disabled entirely on meta for sub-2k users. Otherwise I would have edited it myself.

Comment: @David http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78223/per-site-metas-dont-have-ability-of-suggested-edits/78319#78319

Comment: @angussidney I learn something new about SE every day. thanks.